# How to scroll to the top of each sheet in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running a macro to loop through 7 worksheets.  However, once it's saved and I go to the first worksheet, I'm at the bottom of the table.

I've tried different lines to try and scroll back to the top of all the worksheets within the loop, and none seem to work.

I've tried:

`ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1`

`Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A1"), Scroll:=True`

I know you shouldn't use select, but I've also tried: `.Range("A1").Select`

Any ideas?

```
Sub BrandRank_Pints_IceCream()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Tbl     As ListObject
    Dim Rng     As Range                ' range in which to set the table
    Dim Rl      As Long                 ' last row
    Dim Cl      As Long                 ' last column
    
For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then

'Combine Bear and Dog Data & Delete Rows
    'Find the last used row in Column A
        Dim RngA As Long
            RngA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    'Add Text in Column A, B, and C
        .Cells(RngA, "A").Value = "Blue"
        .Cells(RngA, "B").Value = "Red"
        .Cells(RngA, "C").Value = "TEST"

    'Combine Data containing 'Bear*' and 'Dog*' data
        Dim RngTest As Range
            Set RngTest = .Range("C:C").Find("Test", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        RngTest.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(D:D, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(E:E, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(F:F, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(H:H, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 6).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(I:I, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(J:J, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 8).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(L:L, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        RngTest.Offset(0, 10).Formula = "=sum(sumifs(M:M, C:C, {""Bear*"" , ""Dog*""}))"
        
            RngTest.EntireRow.Copy
                RngTest.EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
'Filter "Bear*" and "Dog*", and Delete Rows
    Dim DataLastRow As Long
        DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Apply Filter
         .Range("A3:M3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("Bear*"" , ""Dog"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'Delete Rows
        .Range("A4:M" & DataLastRow).EntireRow.Delete
         
    'Clear Filter
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
       .Cells.AutoFilter
            
    'Replace Test for Bear/Dog
        RngTest.Replace "Test", "BEAR/DOG"
            
            
'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A3:M
            ' find the last used row in column A
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ' find the last used column in row 3
            Cl = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ' set the range for the table
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
            ' convert the range to a table
            Set Tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Rng, , xlYes)

'Remove / Change Table Format
    With Tbl
        .Name = .Name & "_Table"
        .Range.ClearFormats
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium10"
        .Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Range.Font.Size = 16

'Apply a filter to $ Share for all Brands (Largest to Smallest)
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.clear
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
        .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
        .ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False
    End With
 
'Update $ - % Chg Formula
    .Range("G4").Formula = "=IFERROR((F4/(F4-H4))-1,"""")"
    .Range("G4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    .Range("G4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("G4:G" & DataLastRow)
      
'Update Units - % Chg Formula
    .Range("L4").Formula = "=IFERROR((K4/(K4-M4))-1,"""")"
    .Range("L4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    .Range("L4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("L4:L" & DataLastRow)
    
'Insert 3 Rows
    .Rows("20:22").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Range("C20").Value = "ALL OTHER"
    .Range("C21").Value = "GRAND TOTAL"
    
'Add Formulas to ALL OTHER
    Dim aOther As Range
            Set aOther = .Range("C:C").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        
            aOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 4).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 2).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 5).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 3).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 6).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 5).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 8).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 6).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 6).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 9).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 7).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 7).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 10).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 8).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 8).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 11).Address & ")"
            aOther.Offset(0, 10).Formula = "=SUM(" & aOther.Offset(3, 10).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 13).Address & ")"

'Add Formulas to Grand Total
    .Range("F21").Formula = "=Sum(F4:F20)"
    .Range("H21").Formula = "=Sum(H4:H20)"
    .Range("K21").Formula = "=Sum(K4:K20)"
    .Range("M21").Formula = "=Sum(M4:M20)"
    
'Update Column Format
    .Columns("D").NumberFormat = "0.0"
    .Columns("E").NumberFormat = "0.0"
    .Columns("F").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "0.0"
    .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "0.0"
    .Columns("K").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Columns("M").NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    
    .Range("D3").Value = "$ SHARE"
    .Range("E3").Value = "$ SHARE CHG"
    .Range("F3").Value = "$"
    .Range("G3").Value = "$ - % CHG"
    .Range("H3").Value = "$ - ABS CHG"
    .Range("I3").Value = "UNITS SHARE"
    .Range("J3").Value = "UNITS SHARE CHG"
    .Range("K3").Value = "UNITS"
    .Range("L3").Value = "UNITS - % CHG"
    .Range("M3").Value = "UNITS - ABS CHG"
    

    .Columns("D:M").EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Columns("D:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
'Highlight Grand Total Row
    Dim gTotal As Range
        Set gTotal = .Range("C:C").Find("Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        With gTotal
            .EntireRow.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .EntireRow.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        End With

'Highlight BRAND Row
    Dim Brand As Range
        Set Brand = .Range("C:C").Find("BRAND", LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            
            With Brand
                Brand.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 13).BorderAround , xlThick, -11489280
            End With

    Application.Goto Reference:=Range("A1"), Scroll:=True

        End If
    End With
Next Ws

'Save File
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim TemplatePath As String
        TemplatePath = ""
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TemplatePath & "BrandRank - Template" & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: In your Goto you need a sheet reference - ws.

Comment: try a . in front of your range reference like: Application.Goto Reference:=.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True

Comment: @SJR if the line is within a `With Ws` Loop.  why do I need to reference/qualify the `ws.`?

Comment: In a `With` clause it's the dot which ties the line to whatever the `With` refers. Otherwise it's equivalent to no reference and hence the active sheet is implied. So you don't need `ws` you just need a dot if that line is inside `With`.

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the clarification.  The .range worked!

Answer (score 0):

Please, try `Ws.Activate: Ws.Range("A1").Select`... Why scrolling?

Comment: That was one of the three lines I tried.  It worked for the first sheet, but not the others.

Comment: Why scrolling? Because you need to scroll to actually move the focus to `A1`. I think the answer is already in a comment - the `Range("A1")` needs to be qualified with the worksheet in the `Application.GoTo` line.

Comment: @Cari Day: Try, please `Ws.Activate: Ws.Range("A1").Select` at the iteration end...

Comment: @BigBen: I am afraid that `Application.GoTo` will, anyhow, activate the sheet to be scrolled...

Comment: Yes but you don't need to activate the sheet and then select the cell. A small improvement I know but might as well use it.

Comment: @SJR: I can admit that... :)